# Android API 21 async GET request not working

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, httprequest

I've implemented an Android app, and have not had any issues so far.

But getting an async GET request to work has taken me about 3 days, and still no progress.

I tried using the Android documentations and wrote some code.. no result
And then I tried almost every solution there is online.. again no result

Would you please give me your solution to an async GET request in Android API level 21?

```
    getRequest task = new getRequest();
    String contents = null;

    try {
        contents = task.execute(url).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here's my class

```
public static class getRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("headerFieldName", "I took out the fields here since they were personal");

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                result += (char) data;
                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return "Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using org.apache, but the library has been removed from API level 23.

Thank you!

Comment: Post some code, please! Lets see what you have until now and it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @TodorKostov Just added the code, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a simple Get Request Example Using `HttpsUrlConnection`:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(your_url_address);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        //Parse Response
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

If the Boilerplate code for `AsyncTask` or Networking in general is too much, you can try using networking libraries like `OkHttp` or `Retrofit`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html) you can find a tutorial for a library called OkHttp.